# To make the object variable private in another class

Tags: java

I have written the code this expected output:

Sample input :

> Enter the passenger name:
>   Priya
>
> Enter the gender(M or F / m or f):
>   F
>
> Enter the age:
>   61
>
> Enter the ticket no:
>   140
>
> Enter the ticket price:
>   500.0

Sample Output 1 :

> Ticket no:143
>
> Passenger Name:Priya
>
> Price of a ticket : 500.0
>
> Total Amount : 375.0

I have to change the total amount value based on the age and gender for which I have written function.

My code:
Person.java

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private char gender;
    private int age;
    public void setName(String name ){
        this.name = name;
    }
    public void setGender(char gender){
        this.gender = gender ;
    }
    public void setAge(int age ){
        this.age = age;
    }
    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }
    public char getGender(){
        return this.gender;
    }
    public int getAge(){
        return this.age;
    }
}
```

BusTicket.java

```
public class BusTicket {
    private int ticketNo;
    private float ticketPrice;
    private float totalAmount;
    Person person = new Person();
    int age = person.getAge();
    char g = person.getGender();
    public void setTicketNo(int ticketNo){
        this.ticketNo = ticketNo;
    }
    public void setTicketPrice(float ticketPrice){
        this.ticketPrice = ticketPrice;
    }
    public void setTotalAmount(float totalAmount){
        this.totalAmount = totalAmount;
    }
    public void calculateTotal()
    {  
        if(age<16)
        {
            totalAmount = ticketPrice/2;
            setTotalAmount(totalAmount);
        }
            else if(age>=60)
        {
            totalAmount = 3*(ticketPrice/4);
            setTotalAmount(totalAmount);
        }
        else if(g == 'f'|| g== 'F')
        {
            totalAmount = 9*(ticketPrice/10);
            setTotalAmount(totalAmount);
        }
        else{
            setTotalAmount(ticketPrice);
        }
    }
    public int getTicketNo(){
        return this.ticketNo;
    }
    public float getTicketPrice(){
        return this.ticketPrice;
    }
    public float getTotalAmount(){
        return this.totalAmount;
    } 
}
```

TestMain.java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class TestMain {
    public static BusTicket getTicketDetails()
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        BusTicket bt = new BusTicket();
        System.out.println("Enter the ticket no:");
        bt.setTicketNo(sc.nextInt());
        System.out.println("Enter the ticket price:");
        bt.setTicketPrice(sc.nextFloat());
        return bt;
    }
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Person p = new Person();
        BusTicket bt;
        System.out.println("Enter the passenger name:");
        p.setName(sc.nextLine());
        System.out.println("Enter the gender(M or F/ m or f):");
        p.setGender(sc.next().charAt(0));
        System.out.println("Enter the age:");
        p.setAge(sc.nextInt());
        bt = getTicketDetails();
        System.out.println("Ticket no:"+bt.getTicketNo());
        System.out.println("Passenger Name:"+p.getName());
        System.out.println("Price of a ticket : "+bt.getTicketPrice());
        System.out.println("Total Amount : "+bt.getTotalAmount());

    }

}
```

But my TotalAmount value is always coming 0.0, it is not getting updated.
And some test cases are failed please help to resolve them:

Fail 1 -
Incorrect access specifier/modifier for person -Should be a [private]

Fail 2 -
Check whether the signature(Returntype/Argument/AccessSpecifier/MethodName) of the method setPerson is correct

Fail 3-
Check whether the signature(Returntype/Argument/AccessSpecifier/MethodName) of the method getPerson is correct

Please Help

Thanks

Comment: You need to call `bt.calculateTotal()` before print the total amount.

Comment: As @Héctor Has already mentioned you have to call `calculateTotal` Method, just a suggestion this function should be in different class somethig like `TicketGenerator`, bus ticket is a real-world object which does not know how to calcuate the total value

Comment: @GhostCatsaysReinstateMonica I will remain this in future.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `calculateTotal` to update `totalAmount`. Otherwise, it will be always `0.0`.

```
...
System.out.println("Price of a ticket : "+bt.getTicketPrice());
bt.calculateTotal(); // Add this line
System.out.println("Total Amount : "+bt.getTotalAmount());
```

Answer (score 0):

In your BusTicket class a new Person object is assigned to Person attribute and then you are trying to get age and gender details from that newly created Person object, but at this moment Person's age and gender are not populated yet.

```
  Person person = new Person();
  int age = person.getAge();
```

That's why you are getting 0. What should ideally happen is, you should pass the person object created using the input details to the BusTicket class and populate the BusTicket's person attribute with that person.For now I ll tell just that. :)

Give a try :)

Comment: Now, I am getting the TotalAmount, but can you please help to solve the fail test cases

Answer (score 0):

In your `BusTicket` class, create a getter and setter for the `Person` object, and set the value from the `main` method.